# huge latency with python model

Tags: django, django-models

I've a classical model as:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=200)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I've imported 5839 entries and now I cannot access or create a new Category entry, my browser keep in an infinite loop.
Is there something wrong with my code or, is there best practices to referer self as parent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can speed up the admin by using [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.raw_id_fields) for your `parent` foreign key:

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    raw_id_fields = ('parent',)
    ...

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

Comment: yep it works thanks. My aim is to import data from https://www.google.com/basepages/producttype/taxonomy.en-US.txt